# Finding all spec types in a directory and sub directories using mocha

Tags: javascript

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ignore-styles setup.js src/**/*.spec.js --compilers js:babel-core/register"
  },
```

I have this code in my `package.json` however I have `spec.js` files on different levels and it wont pick them up.

so far this `src/**/*.spec.js` is picking up `.spec.js` files in `src/header/index.js` however I want a way to find all `.spec.js` below `src` level

Comment: Please revise your title and question to be more specific.  It looks like your question is perhaps just about mocha--or perhaps about running it as a node script

Comment: @STW have done.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --require ignore-styles setup.js **/*.spec.js --compilers js:babel-core/register"
},
```